# Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to Id

Tags: apex, custom-field, lookup, error-messages

I get an error when I try to update lookup field in apex.

Here is the method implementation:

```
public void addTaskCommentHistory(Task task) {
    if(task == Null) {
            return;
    }

    String newValue = task.Description;

    if(newValue != Null && !newValue.equals('')) {
        String taskId = task.Id;
        String fieldName = 'Comments';
        String oldValue = '';

        Task_History__c taskHistory = new Task_History__c();
        taskHistory.Task_ID__c = taskId;
        taskHistory.Field_Name__c = fieldName;
        taskHistory.Old_Value__c = oldValue;
        taskHistory.New_Value__c = newValue;


        String lastModifiedBy = task.LastModifiedById; 
        String userName = '';
        // the query will return no more than one row because the data is extracted by user id
        List<User> listOfUsers = [SELECT Name FROM User where Id = :lastModifiedBy];
        if(listOfUsers.size() > 0){
            User user = listOfUsers.get(0);
            userName = user.Name;
        }

        taskHistory.User__c = user.Name;

        insert taskHistory;
    }    
}
```

When I try to add `user.Name` to `taskHistory.User__c` in `taskHistory.User__c = user.Name` I get

> Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to Id

Please advise how to update the User__c lookup field without the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex is case-insensitive language (not like java or JS), so be careful in naming variables.

You have problem here

```
taskHistory.User__c = user.Name;
```

`user.Name` is just a name of User. It is not its unique identifier. In order to populate lookup, fill `User__c` with `id` of user. To fix your problem, replace it.

```
List<User> listOfUsers = [SELECT Name FROM User where Id = :lastModifiedBy];
if(listOfUsers.size() > 0){
    User user = listOfUsers.get(0);
    userName = user.Name;
}
taskHistory.User__c = user.Name;
```

with:

```
List<User> listOfUsers = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User where Id = :lastModifiedBy];
if(listOfUsers.size() > 0){
    User usr = listOfUsers.get(0);
    userName = usr.Name;
    taskHistory.User__c = usr.Id;
}
```

Comment: I did it the way you suggested "taskActivityHistory.User__c = user.Id;" but I still get the same error message: "Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to Id"

Comment: @sfdcadm did you change `User user = listOfUsers.get(0);` to `User usr = listOfUsers.get(0);` ?

Comment: In `taskHistory.User__c = user.Id;` the `user` variable is not in the scope as it's been declared inside the `if` condition

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy and highfive. Thank you both it worked. However as far as I'm concerned I migh be allowed to mark only one best answer.

Comment: my 5 cents: I do believe that you do not need to modify the query to include `Id`, it is always queried automatically

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that:

```
user.Name
```

is an [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm) token because the symbol `user` is resolved to be an [SObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm).

(This is where Apex's case insensitivity is annoying: in case sensitive languages it is normal to use say `User` for the type and `user` for a variable and the compiler treats them as different symbols: in Apex they are the same symbol. So best to use names that differ by more than case, say `User` for the type and say `u` for the variable.)

Your `user` variable can only be referenced within the `{}` it is declared in.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup fields should have the Id of the related object. Try assigning the `user.Id`.

```
List<User> listOfUsers = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User where Id = :lastModifiedBy];
if(listOfUsers.size() > 0){
    User user = listOfUsers.get(0);
    userName = user.Name;
    taskHistory.User__c = user.Id;
}
```